# Bootstrap Side Nav disable horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a side nav that I plan on using for my site. However, when I resize the screen to mobile and open the side menu, the scroll wheel becomes visible and am able to scroll of to the side horizontally. I want to disable this from happening so that when the side nav is open, horizontal scroll becomes locked/disabled. I've been trying to figure out how to disable it but cannot figure out how. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried the css `width:100%; overflow-x:hidden;` but that did not work.

[Here is the Codepen](http://codepen.io/GeeShepherd/pen/dXZANY)

Answer (score -1):

I would switch to using `transform` instead:

```
.body-slide-in {
 tranform: translateX(200px);
}
```

Transform will move the div visually without altering it's actual position in the DOM. This will be far less likely to cause layout, overflow or position issues.

EDIT--

However, if you wish to use the overflow option, try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `.container-fluid` div directly above the `.body-slide-in` element. It should work.